# Como mostrar as imagens dos ícones na Action Bar Android?

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Eu criei uma simples aplicação, é algo muito trivial mesmo. O que está acontecendo é que estou tentando criar um menu com ícones na **Action Bar**, mas o que de fato acontecendo é que a minha aplicação mostra somente um simples menu sem mostrar os ícones. Eu já pesquisei em vários lugares, tentei acompanhar vários vídeos no YOUTUBE. Quando percebi que a mesma maneira que estava sendo ensinado na internet e   na documentação oficial do Android era a mesma forma que estou fazendo no meu projeto imaginei que fosse problema de bug do meu dispositivo virtual, ou seja, achei que o problema era na meu emulador de Android do meu computador local, então resolvi habilitar o modo desenvolvedor do meu smartphones, e ao executar gerou o mesmo problema. Então eu concluir que o problema era código mesmo, o problema está no meu projeto, agora somente basta eu tentar identificar onde está o problema e corrigir.

Essa imagem abaixo é o **Preview** da minha IDE de desenvolvimento, era dessa forma que eu esperava que minha aplicação se comportasse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando vou executar a minha aplicação ela se comporta da forma totalmente diferente. Veja e acompanhe na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o meu projeto é pequeno eu vou colocar o código de todo meu projeto aqui, e gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a identificar onde está esse possível problema e por favor pudessem me ajudar a corrigir.

Essa é minha activity.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Esse é meu arquivo XML principal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Esse é meu menu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_download"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
        android:title="Download"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_open"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="Abrir"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
        android:title="Adicionar"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Essa é a configuração principal que faz tudo funcionar corretamente, pelo menos era para funcionar corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes estava assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E modifiquei e ficou assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tirei dúvidas com alguns colegas desenvolvedores, eles me informaram que quando usamos o editor gráfico da IDE é recomendável que se faça um analise do código que a IDE está compondo para você, foi exatamente isso que houve de errado. O editor gráfico criou para mim umas linhas de código que o Frameworks costuma usar, eu simplesmente substituir a tag **app** por **android**, que é uma tag nativas do Android.